# requires unavailable shared library com.sec.android.app.multiwindow; failing (enabling multiwindow )

Tags: android

Can i Achieve MultiWindow support in Android open source, ie., if i sync the latest android source repo ? or is it only works on Samsung Galexy NOte ?

I tried adding following in manifest

```
 <uses-library 
                    android:required="true" 
            android:name="com.sec.android.app.multiwindow" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.an droid.support.multiwindow" android:value="true" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.DEFAULT_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_W" android:value="632.0dip" />
<meta-data android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.MINIMUM_SIZE_H" android:value="598.0dip" />
```

and also

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER"
```

in my main Activity intent filter.

But this I am not able to install it in emulator or any other phone, How can i make a app multiwindow enable ? is that library is closed source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is a vendor extension and will only work on devices that have the required libraries, etc. installed.